# XMLGregorianCalendar to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime

From some generated code I get a
`javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` and I want to convert it to a `LocalDateTime` without any zone-offset (UTC).

My current code accomplishes it, but I think it must be possible to acheaf the same result in a more elegant (and shorter) way.

```
    public static LocalDateTime xmlGregorianCalendar2LocalDateTime(XMLGregorianCalendar xgc) {
        // fix the time to UTC:
        final int offsetSeconds = xgc.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
        final LocalDateTime localDateTime = xgc.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDateTime(); // this simply ignores the timeZone
        return localDateTime.minusSeconds(offsetSeconds); // ajust according to the time-zone offet
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like :

```
xgc.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDateTime() ?
```

If you don't want to just rip off the zone information, but instead get the local time at UTC :

```
ZonedDateTime utcZoned = xgc.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
LocalDateTime ldt = utcZoned.toLocalDateTime();
```

This answer is from the guy who has written the java.time specifications and implemented them btw : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767084/convert-between-localdate-and-xmlgregoriancalendar

Comment: As I wrote in the comment of my code, this ignores the zone-offset -> wrong time (if zone is not +00:00).

Comment: So you just need to convert your zonedDateTime to utcZonedDateTime before converting it to local time, see my completed code.

Comment: Be aware that the conversion from XmlGregorianCalendar to GregorianCalendar has a slight precision loss. Nanoseconds will be dropped. This will be ok in most use cases.